# Why when I do write.csv I don't get the exact same dataframe output as it shows in the global environment

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

In the dataframe I have something that looks like. Im satisfied with this look

```
ID1|PRO1|PRO2|PRO3|PROALL|PROALLINFO
  1   Y     Y    Y      Y   Y/Y/Y
  2                         No PRO1/No PRO2/ No PRO3
  3   Y     Y           Y   Y/Y/No PRO3/
```

In order to get that df i started off with

```
ID1|PRO1|PRO2|PRO3|
  1    Y    Y    Y
  2    N    N    N
  3    Y    Y    N
```

What I did was create a list

```
 PROALL LIST <- c("PRO1","PRO2","PRO3")
```

Then i created a script trying to say whenever one of those values is "Y" then assign "Y" for the new script which worked. Then i made another column based on the results of the cell to add as text in a second column.

```
df2<- df1 %>%
 mutate(PROALL=ifelse(is.na(.[PROALL LIST], "N",Y")) %>%
 mutate(PROALLINFO(ifelse(.$PRO1 == "Y", paste0(ifelse(!is.na(.$PRO1),.$PRO1,"No PRO1"),"/"
 ifelse(!is.na(.$PRO2),.$PRO2,"No PRO2"),"/",ifelse(!is.na(.$PRO3),.$PRO3,"No PRO3"))
```

As i did this script the outcome was the same as the dataframe outcome i have in global environment. The problem is when i do

```
write.csv(df2,"SAMPLE.csv",row.names=FALSE, na="")
```

I get a excel file with these set of columns. All I want it to do is to put out a file that resembles my dataframe in r.

```
ID1|PRO1|PRO2|PRO3|PROALL.PRO1|PROALL.PRO2|PROALL.PRO3|PROALLINFO.PRO1|PROALLINFO.PRO2|PROALLINFO.PRO3
```

Comment: unfortunately you code is not reproduceable due to many typos (missing brakets, etc.)... also it would help to show what the output in the console looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from typos, missing brackets and quotes in the code another issue with the code is `ifelse(is.na(.[PROALL LIST], "N",Y")` returns a matrix and then further code is ran on the matrix. So the final output (`df2`) consists of a dataframe which has a matrix in it. Although it "looks" correct but looking at `str(df2)` would give you the real understanding of the data.

Here is one way to solve this. Note that I have kept the approach general so if the number of columns in `PROALL_LIST` increase the code need not to be changed and it will work for any number of columns.

```
library(dplyr)

PROALL_LIST <- c("PRO1","PRO2","PRO3")

df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(PROALL=ifelse(rowSums(.[PROALL_LIST] == 'Y') > 0, 'Y', 'N')) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(PROALLINFO = {
    x <- c_across(PROALL_LIST)
    paste0(ifelse(x == 'N', paste('No', PROALL_LIST), x), collapse = '/')
  }) %>%
  ungroup
  
df2      

# A tibble: 3 x 6
#    ID1 PRO1  PRO2  PRO3  PROALL PROALLINFO             
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>                  
#1     1 Y     Y     Y     Y      Y/Y/Y                  
#2     2 N     N     N     N      No PRO1/No PRO2/No PRO3
#3     3 Y     Y     N     Y      Y/Y/No PRO3  

str(df2)
#tibble [3 × 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ ID1       : int [1:3] 1 2 3
# $ PRO1      : chr [1:3] "Y" "N" "Y"
# $ PRO2      : chr [1:3] "Y" "N" "Y"
# $ PRO3      : chr [1:3] "Y" "N" "N"
# $ PROALL    : chr [1:3] "Y" "N" "Y"
# $ PROALLINFO: chr [1:3] "Y/Y/Y" "No PRO1/No PRO2/No PRO3" "Y/Y/No PRO3"             

write.csv(df2,"SAMPLE.csv",row.names=FALSE, na="")
```

[image]